# Which Swift features are available on Linux (CoreData, linking to C code)?

Tags: swift

I am interested in writing Swift code on Linux. Now I know I can install Swift on Linux, that's great. Does the Linux installation of Swift also include [CoreData](https://medium.com/xcblog/core-data-with-swift-4-for-beginners-1fc067cca707)? That would be terrific.

Also, is it possible to compile C code and link it to Swift code on Linux, as it is possible on MacOS?

I found [this description](https://swift.org/blog/swift-linux-port/) but it is more than three years old at this point; has there been some progress since then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564576/can-core-data-be-used-on-linux indicates not back in 2010.

Comment: @K7AAY yup, saw that one ... I guess I'm hoping the situation has changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to put C into a Swift Package.  Such C packages can be linked with other Swift Packages. For example, see ["Imported C and Objective-C APIs"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis)

However, CoreData is not part of the cross platform Swift Foundation Libraries.

As a crossplatform from persistant data alternative to CoreData, it is possible to use SQLite C with a layer that provides a Swift API.

[Vapor server and companion iOS app examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47717355/vapor-server-and-companion-ios-app-examples/55368410#55368410) provides a discussion an approach to have C & Swift packages which run cross platform on iOS, macOS and Linux.

Comment: Re your rejected edits on [tag:swift], please (re-)read [the tag wiki excerpt guidance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts), in particular point 4.

Comment: @StephenKitt Unlike Q&A, the tag edit process provides for limited communication and revision. It's voted up or down.  At this moment, [Acer Swift](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=OpenStack+Swift) and [OpenStack Swift](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=Acer+Swift) return as many results the [[swift](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift)] tag on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange. As such, the re-submit comment noted that the _'swift' tag itself can be ambiguous_ in the context of Unix/Linux ... for re-evaluation, per your prior comment. ...

Comment: @StephenKitt ... the tag wiki had _**no text whatsoever**_ when I started trying to proposing what seemed to be a resonable minimal something better than nothing ... https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/518779/revisions. The rejects are OK. Your feedback is appreciated. And, your current edits look like a good example. So, in the end, it took both our efforts to go from zero to something useful. Peace. ;-)